# JavaScript: setting to the callback or the anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, onload, anonymous-function

## MY ISSUE

I've been learning the basics of AJAX from two different internet sources. In the multi-step process of sending an async HTTP request, there's one small **inconsistency in how the** `.onload` **property is called on the XHR request object and then set to** 1) an anonymous function or 2) a callback (??? that's what I think [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload#Syntax) says).

---

## 1ST APPROACH

the `.onload` property is called on the `ourRequest` object and this is **set to an anonymous function**:

```
ourRequest.onload = function() { 
  // the code goes here 
}
```

---

## 2ND APPROACH

the `.onload` property is called on the `asyncRequestObject` object and this is **set to the name of the function (a callback**??):

```
function handleSuccess () { 
  // the code goes here
}

asyncRequestObject.onload = handleSuccess;
```

---

## MY QUESTION(S)

What's the difference between how the 1st and the 2nd approach work?

And then, is there any reason to use the 1st approach over the 2nd approach?

Comment: They're identical except the second uses a named function. When to use which depends on use--if you're using the same handler for a few different events, it makes sense to name the function.

Comment: I think the answers are good so far but they are missing the “anonymous function vs. callback” question. Generally, _callback_ is a role, not a syntactic feature. It says: “if you pass it as an argument, it will called at some point in future”, and it implies that it has to be a function, but it doesn’t require it to be a named, anonymous, arrow function, or class method.

Comment: @ggorlen They are not identical. Function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @jhpratt "except the second uses a named function", yes?

Comment: @ggorlen That doesn't matter except for debugging purposes, really. It's the hoisting (and potential scope pollution) that would matter.

Comment: @jhpratt I assumed the named function term implied/entailed all that but I'm glad you're explicit. The hoisting and scope pollution may be warranted if the function will be used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between how the 1st and the 2nd approach work?

The difference is that the first function is an anonymous **function expression** while the second is a function with a name. Both are event handlers for the "load" event of the XMLHttpRequest .

> And then, is there any reason to use the 1st approach over the 2nd approach?

If you don't plan to reuse your handler somewhere else then you don't need to declare your function with a name.

It is no different than any other programming practice. Use a variable/constant when a value is called multiple times, otherwise use a literal.

Comment: I see, but what if the first approach was with setting the `ourRequest.onload` to a named function? How would it then be different from the second approach?

Comment: it wouldn't be different at all. You'd just have a variable named `handleSuccess ` in the current scope. Do you need such a variable or not is the only question you should ask yourself.

Comment: now in 1st ourRequest.onload is set to a handleSuccess function
`ourRequest.onload = function handleSuccess() { }`
2nd
`function handleSuccess () { }
asyncRequestObject.onload = handleSuccess;` what do you mean when you say that in the 1st case I'd have a variable named handleSuccess in the current scope?

Comment: `function handleSuccess(){ }` is somehow like to writing `var handleSuccess = function(){ }` . you are declaring a variable named `handleSuccess` . If you declare the function 2 times and affect it to asyncRequestObject.onload 2 times it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

A function declaration creates a (hoisted) variable in the current scope, that has the same name as the function, and whose value is a reference to that function.

A function expression simply evaluates as a reference to that function.

So the primary difference is that where you use `handleSuccess`, you can continue to reference the function for other purposes elsewhere.

Comment: how about now that in the 1st approach ourRequest.onload is set to a handleSuccess function
`ourRequest.onload = function handleSuccess() { }`
and 2nd remains the same 
`function handleSuccess () { }
asyncRequestObject.onload = handleSuccess;` is setting to a callback better in same cases than setting to a named function?